# Surprise attack by Dog

Tags: dogs, behavior

So here's the situation: I have a black male lab, currently 1.5 years old. We meet many small kids while taking walk. Usually, the kids taunt my lab and call him "kukur"(literally means "Dog", but here in India it is generally a bad word) for fun. Recently, I am noticing my dog giving a surprise attack to anyone walking by even though seems like he is busy smelling around. I thought this only happens when my dog feels threatened(people usually give stares in my dog's eye when passing by, which I think must be the cause of this action and also the kids getting on nerve of my dog).

He is usually very friendly around anybody and still is, but this above behavior is concerning. He is decently leash trained.

**More info**: We also have stray dogs, they are nowhere close to wanting to befriend my dog. I have to avoid them as they show warning signs.

**The kid's situation**: They stand in the way of my path or running and tease my dog. These kids have some wrong notion that Labrador doesn't attack or bite. I cannot say anything to them, they just don't listen, and usually my dog barks them away(not attack).

So, is this surprise attack concerning? He doesn't surprise attack everyone I don't think it is an attack(or can be) since he doesn't growl or bark. What should I do?

Sorry for the bad English.

Comment: Can you describe your dog's behaviour in more detail? Does he growl, bark, show his teeth, what does his body language look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe these kids are the source of your problem. These attacks are warning signs from your dog, telling the kids to back off.  I would tell these kids to back off and stop taunting your dog.

Also, try to remember that dogs live to survive and anything that threatens that will cause a negative reaction from your dog.  Dogs don't talk in words like we do, they use sounds and body language as a means of communication.  A growl is an attempt to say "hey, I don't like this."  If the initiating behavior is left undisciplined the dog will escalate to growls with lunges and then growls with lunges and bites.  Try to remember as well that dogs feel everyone's energy.  If you anticipate the aggressive act the dog will feel your weakness and become defensive to protect you.

Comment: Yes, that worked, I started to not walk my dog in the kids' area. He stopped doing these surprise attacks.